# paragraph doesnt go to new line

Tags: javascript, html, css

im creating a calculator with html,css and js.
now i have a problem in html and css.
my calculator has a `section` for a `paragraph` that displays users entered number and operators. the problem is here: when user enters a lot of number, `p` will go out of calculator but it should go to new line! [you can see what i mean in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ddmn.png)

here is the important part of html and css code:

```css
.container div {
  font-size: x-large;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.60);
  border-radius: 5px;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.30s;
}

.container div:not(.result):hover {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.70);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 3.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 3.5px);
}

.result {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 6;
}

.result p {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="div1 result"><p class="show"></p></div>
        <div class="div2"><p>+/-</p></div>
        <div class="div3 number"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="div4 number"><p>4</p></div>
        <div class="div5 number"><p>7</p></div>
        <div class="div6 clean"><p>C</p></div>
        <div class="div7"><p>( )</p></div>
        <div class="div8 number"><p>8</p></div>
        <div class="div9 number"><p>5</p></div>
        <div class="div10 number"><p>2</p></div>
        <div class="div11 number"><p>0</p></div>
        <div class="div12"><p>%</p></div>
        <div class="div13 number"><p>9</p></div>
        <div class="div14 number"><p>6</p></div>
        <div class="div15 number"><p>3</p></div>
        <div class="div16"><p>.</p></div>
        <div class="div17"><p>&#247;</p></div>
        <div class="div18"><p>&#215;</p></div>
        <div class="div19"><p>_</p></div>
        <div class="div20"><p>+</p></div>
        <div class="div21"><p>=</p></div>
    </section>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: The code you provided doesn't behave remotely like the picture. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using this

When the text overflows in width use ---> `word-break: break-word;`  to break up the text(or numbers in this case)

you can also add  `height: fit-content;` to ajust the height of the div to your text or numbers